# What about using salt to avoid hash table collision?

Tags: string, hash, hashmap, hashtable, salt

If a key collides in a hash table, I want to find another position by salting the key, recursively, until I find a free position (always using the same salt).

For example:

1. "bee" and "ant" hash to 7
2. I insert "bee" in the table.
3. Then when I insert "ant", it collides, I salt "ant" with "!23" (resulting in "!23ant") and call insert again (I store the original key, but use the salted key to get an index).

I searched for hash tables with this method, but did't find any material on it.

What are the downsides of this approach to collision handling?

Comment: Are you using a fixed salt to resolve the collision? Or do you pick a new salt each time?

Comment: fixed salt. In my example, always the string "!23"

Comment: What do you do if you get a second collision? (By the way, the technique you're describing is related to a bunch of other hashing strategies, but I want to make sure I understand your system before I go into them.)

Comment: I recursively salt the key: `ant => !23ant => !23!23ant => …` (I assume a hashing function that produces very different hashes for small changes in the key)

Answer (score 1):

From a performance perspective, each hash collision requires you to build a new string, which can take a long time if your input string is long. Also note that the cost of building this string increases as you get more and more hash collisions, so the price of a successful lookup ends up depending quadratically on how many collisions you had.

Comparing this salt based approach to other hashing approaches, I'd suspect that this extra cost would make your system slower in practice than other techniques like linear probing or double hashing, which might not have as good a distribution as your approach but don't have to do as much work to compute hash codes and construct auxiliary strings.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot see how this solves any problem. Let's play a bit with such collisions:

```
// Here you would store "bee" and "bug" with the hashes 7 and 8:
"bee" = 7
"bug" = 8

// Here you get a collision and add a "salt":
"bee" = 7
"ant" = 7 -> "!23ant" -> 8

// Depending on the adding order, you can end up with "bug"=8 or with "!23bug=9"
"bee" = 7
"!23ant" = 8
"bug" = 8 -> "!23bug" -> 9
```

So how would you know whether you have to search with "bug" or with "!23bug" to get the hash. Storing this information would negate the advantage of a fast hashmap.